# concat() got multiple values for argument 'ignore_index'

Tags: python, pandas

Hi I'm getting this result, could you explain why?

```
data1980 = pd.read_excel ('/home/gsubuntu/Documents/כנרת/EXCEL/גולמיים/r1980.xlsx', sheet_name='גיליון1',encoding = "ISO-8859-8")

data1990 = pd.read_excel ('/home/gsubuntu/Documents/כנרת/EXCEL/גולמיים/r1990.xlsx', sheet_name='גיליון1',encoding = "ISO-8859-8")

data2000 = pd.read_excel ('/home/gsubuntu/Documents/כנרת/EXCEL/גולמיים/r2000.xlsx', sheet_name='גיליון1',encoding = "ISO-8859-8")

data2010 = pd.read_excel ('/home/gsubuntu/Documents/כנרת/EXCEL/גולמיים/r2010.xlsx', sheet_name='גיליון1',encoding = "ISO-8859-8")
​

rdata = pd.concat([data1980],[data1990],[data2000],[data2010],ignore_index=True)
​
​
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [7], in <module>
      3 data2000 = pd.read_excel ('/home/gsubuntu/Documents/כנרת/EXCEL/גולמיים/r2000.xlsx', sheet_name='גיליון1',encoding = "ISO-8859-8")
      4 data2010 = pd.read_excel ('/home/gsubuntu/Documents/כנרת/EXCEL/גולמיים/r2010.xlsx', sheet_name='גיליון1',encoding = "ISO-8859-8")
----> 6 rdata = pd.concat([data1980],[data1990],[data2000],[data2010],ignore_index=True)

TypeError: concat() got multiple values for argument 'ignore_index'
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You should put these in a single list as the first argument

```
  pd.concat([data1, data2, data3],ignore_index=True)
```

docs: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.concat.html